# Dictionary breaks Source Generator

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators

I´ve been trying something out with source generators and encountered a weird issue.

The source generator will be executed successfully only one time after making changes to it´s code, but will fail every subsequent run with this:

```
CSC : warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer Generator cannot be created from MyDir\CodeGeneration\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\CodeGeneration.dll : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..
```

I removed parts of the code one by one and tracked it down to this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<Table, object>> Properties { get; } = new();
```

It´s a dictionary I wanted to populate through reflection to generate derived classes.
If I remove the dicitionary the issue disappears. Also if I replace `Table` with something else.

There is nothing special about `Table` though:

```
    public class Table
    {
        public virtual int Object_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual int Schema_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; } = "";

        public Table()
        {
        }

        public Table(int object_ID, int schema_ID, string name)
        {
            Object_ID = object_ID;
            Schema_ID = schema_ID;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

My guess is that referencing other projects from a source generator (in this case a .net standard 2.0 class library) is causing issues? Not being able to use reflection in source generation seems like quite the limitation though?

For completeness, the generator I used to test this with:

```
    [Generator]
    public class Generator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Func<Generator, object>> Properties { get; } = new();
        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {

        }

        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Debugger.Launch();
            }
#endif
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think step 1 is to find out what your exception is... You should really be using unit tests to develop your analyzer, which makes this trivial

Comment: Referencing separate libraries from an SG requires some special steps, see [the cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#use-functionality-from-nuget-packages). It's not clear why you want to use reflection though -- in a source generator you're normally looking at code *which is being compiled*, and so reflection isn't available. You'd use the (more powerful) APIs provided by Roslyn instead

Comment: Did you look at code in the Execute() method?

Comment: I´ve encountered that with Packages and managed to get the ones I need to work, I can´t seem to find the equivalent steps required for Project references though. I want to use reflection because I´m getting objects of the type Table from a json and need the value of each virtual property, for which I´ll need their GetMethods (unless there is a way to construct funcs from the syntax?). I´m sure my reasons for doing this are flawed and there is probably a better way...

Comment: I've really no idea what you're trying to do, what `Table` is, or how you're using reflection. None of that information is in your question. I'm not sure that's related to your exception though -- you **really** need to look at the actual exception for this, not just that wrapper. Anything else is a waste of time. Note that VS is very bad at reloading source generates after they're changed (see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/48083)), which might be misleading you. Like I said, develop your SG using unit tests, not by debugging in VS

Comment: @canton7 you are right I should probably do that. I´m still fairly new to source generation and have not engaged with unit testing SGs yet, so I´m unsure about how even to get started with that.

Answer (score 0):

canton7s link to the cookbook and suggestions about package references actually lead me to the solution in [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/47517#discussioncomment-1624292).

In the project that is consuming the generator, I needed to change the existing reference to the class library that defines `Table` to include `OutputItemType="Analyzer"`.

`ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"` was not needed in my case though.